# How Can I Make My Character Spawn Without Crossing With A Block

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am making a game where my character can teleport on a click within a radius. I added raycast so my character won't try to get in blocks on teleport. But when I click just right above a block, because my character's center point teleports to the position, the bottom part of it stays under the block and then it goes up.
I wanna do something like this:
if the player tries to summon a place where it will collide with a block, the place it will spawn will be above where the player clicked so that there will be no crossing.
I clearly don't know how to do that, so please help me.

Here is my code

```
public class PlayerSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public Vector2 groundChecker;
    public float castDistance;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Update()
    {
        //If character is on ground and left mouse button is clicked, check how far the point you clicked from the player and teleport
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && IsGrounded())
        {
            //Calculating distance between mouse clicked point and player point
            Vector2 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
            Vector2 clickedPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector2 distanceFromPlayer = clickedPosition - playerPosition;

            //Checking if mouse clicked point is a game object that can't be teleported
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity);

            if(hit.collider == null)
            {
                if (distanceFromPlayer.magnitude < 3)
                {
                    player.transform.position = clickedPosition;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Vector2 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(playerPosition, 5);
    }


    public bool IsGrounded()
    {
        if(Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, groundChecker, 0, -transform.up, castDistance, groundLayer))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is a photo from the game
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could solve this problem:

Option 1: Change the sprite "Dave"'s sorting point to bottom center (x: 0.5, y: 0), this will make the center point of the object be at that bottom center, resulting on the object's feet being where the user clicks.

Option 2: Use `hit.collider.bounds` to calculate the Y position of the topmost part of the block:

```
Bounds blockBounds = hit.collider.bounds;
float topmostY = blockBounds.center.y + blockBounds.extents.y;
```

Assuming you did not implement `Option 1` (thus Dave's center point still being at the center of the sprite) the correct place to spawn the player should be at the topmostY + half of the player's height:

```
float playerHeight = playerCollider.bounds.extents.y;
Vector2 finalSpawnPoint = new(clickedPosition.x, topmostY + playerHeight);
player.transform.position = finalSpawnPoint;
```

Option 3: Raycast from the sky, at the X position where the user clicked, going directly down, hitting only the ground layer. You can then use `RaycastHit.point` in order to calculate the Y position of where the player should be (using the height calculation on Option 2).

Here's a sample script with the implementation of option 2:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject player;
    [SerializeField] private Collider2D playerCollider;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 groundChecker;
    [SerializeField] private float castDistance;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    private void Update()
    {
        //If character is on ground and left mouse button is clicked, check how far the point you clicked from the player and teleport
        if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || !IsGrounded())
            return;
        
        //Calculating distance between mouse clicked point and player point
        Vector2 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
        Vector2 clickedPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 distanceFromPlayer = clickedPosition - playerPosition;

        //Checking if mouse clicked point is a game object that can't be teleported
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity);
        
        if (distanceFromPlayer.magnitude >= 3)
            return;

        if (hit.collider == null)
        {
            player.transform.position = clickedPosition;
        }
        else // consider adding a check to make sure the hit object belongs to a valid layer
        {
            Bounds blockBounds = hit.collider.bounds;
            float topmostY = blockBounds.center.y + blockBounds.extents.y;
            float playerHeight = playerCollider.bounds.extents.y;
            Vector2 finalSpawnPoint = new(clickedPosition.x, topmostY + playerHeight);
            player.transform.position = finalSpawnPoint;
        }
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Vector2 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(playerPosition, 5);
    }

    public bool IsGrounded()
    {
        if (Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, groundChecker, 0, -transform.up, castDistance, groundLayer))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Source APIs

- Collider bounds: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-bounds.html
- Bounds (struct): https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html
- RaycastHit: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D.html
- RaycastHit.point: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-point.html

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking your time and writing this. I was thinking a similar thing with option 3. I thought if we raycast to all 4 directions on click and calculate distance between clicked position and the object in each direction.

x = Dave's hight
y = distance between clicked position and nearest object

1) Send rays to 4 side
2) If it collides an object with Ground tag, calculate distance(y)
3) If distance(y) < x/2 (half of the height)
4) player.transform.position = clicked position + (x/2 - y)

I wonder what you think about this and how do I make this a code

Comment: And what is [SerializeField] and why do we use them may I ask. (I am pretty new into this stuff)